WooCommerce Custom Payment Gateway Payment Fields
I'm trying to build a custom payment gateway for WooCommerce.
I'm trying to add custom payment field once the user selects my payment gateway. I'm using payment_fields() function to accomplish it. However, when I select the custom payment method during checkout, I don't see an option to enter my paystring. The payment_fields() method is never getting called. Below is the code snippet for my payment_fields() function:
public function payment_fields() {
        error_log('In payemnt fields method');
        ?>
        <fieldset id="paystring_field" style="display:none;">
            <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="paystring"><?php _e( 'PayString', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="input-text" name="paystring" id="paystring" placeholder="Enter your PayString" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        <?php
}


Did you add $this->has_fields = true; to the constructor?
